# Definition of Euclidian connection on vector bundle

Tags: differential-forms, vector-bundles, connections

In my Global Analysis course at university we saw the notion of *Euclidean connection* on vector bundle and I do not quite understand its definition. Let me recall the settings.

Let $\pi: E \to M$ be a smooth vector bundle. We define a *connection* on $E$ as an $\mathbb R$-linear map
$$\nabla: \Gamma(E) \to \Omega^1(E) = \Gamma(T^*M \otimes E) = \Omega^1(M)\otimes \Gamma(E),$$
such that
$$\nabla (fs) = df \otimes s + f \nabla s$$
for all $f \in C^\infty(M)$ and $s \in \Gamma(E)$. Now we say that $E$ has a Euclidean structure if there exists $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle \in \Gamma(E^*\otimes E^*)$ such that
$$\langle v, w \rangle = \langle w, v \rangle, \quad \text{for } v \neq 0, ~\langle v, v \rangle > 0$$
for $v, w \in \Gamma(E)$. Afterwards, my teacher said that a connection $\nabla$ was called Euclidean if
$$d\langle v, w \rangle = \langle \nabla v, w \rangle + \langle v, \nabla w \rangle $$
for $v, w \in \Gamma(E)$. However, I am not sure to see what he meant by this, because $\nabla v \in \Omega^1(M)\otimes \Gamma(E)$ so that $\langle \nabla v, w \rangle$ doesn't really make sense. If we write
$$\nabla v = \sum_{j = 1}^n v_j \otimes e_j,$$
can we say that $\langle \nabla v, w \rangle$ is in fact equal to
$$\sum_{j = 1}^n v_j \otimes \langle e_j, w \rangle \in \Omega^1(M)?$$
This makes sense because $\langle v, w \rangle \in C^\infty(M)$ so that $d\langle v, w \rangle \in \Omega^1(M)$. But still, I am not totally sure. Could one of you enlighten me with this ? Maybe there is a reference where all of this is well-explained ?

Comment: Your expression for $\nabla v$ is confusing to me. I would write $v=\sum v_ie_i$, where $e_i$ is a frame for $E$ and $v_i$ are scalar fields. Then $$\nabla v = \sum dv_i\otimes e_i + v_i\nabla e_i = \sum_i (dv_i+\sum_j v_j\omega_{ji})\otimes e_i.$$ Here $\nabla e_i = \sum \omega_{ij}\otimes e_j$ gives you the usual connection $1$-forms.

Comment: Ok I see, but then do we have 
$$\langle \nabla s_1, s_2\rangle = \sum_i \left(dv_i + \sum_j v_j \omega_{ji}\right)\otimes \langle e_i, s_2\rangle ?$$

Comment: Yes, but no tensor sign there, as the inner products are just scalars. Just a linear combination of $1$-forms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It could help to see $\Gamma(T^{*}M \otimes E)$ simply as $\text{Hom}(TM,E)$. This is the case because if $\sigma\in\Gamma(T^{*}M \otimes E)$, then for every $p\in M$ we have
$$\sigma_{p}\in \left(T_{p}M\right)^{*}\otimes E_p\simeq \text{Hom}(T_p M,E_p).$$
This explains why we sometimes call $\sigma\in\Gamma(T^{*}M \otimes E)$ a differential $1$-form with values in $E$.
Now, if $v,w\in\Gamma(E)$, then $\nabla v\in \text{Hom}(TM,E)$ and therefore the differential $1$-form $\langle \nabla v,w\rangle\in\Omega^{1}(M)$ is defined simply as
$$\langle \nabla v,w\rangle_{p}(u):=\langle \nabla v\vert_{p}(u), w\vert_{p}\rangle_{p}\in\mathbb{R}$$
for all $p\in M$ and $u\in T_{p}M$.

Comment: Ok I think I see, nice way to see it. Just I assume that we have $\Gamma(T^*M \otimes E) \cong \Gamma(\text{Hom(TM, E)})$ rather than $\Gamma(T^*M \otimes E) \cong \text{Hom(TM, E)}$ right ?

Comment: oops... yes of course!